# Writing JSON children in R

Tags: json, r

I have a data set that I would like to group in JSON.

```
                       address         city.x state.x latitude.x longitude.x
    1 5601 W. Slauson Ave. #200    Culver City      CA   33.99718  -118.40145
    2                 PO 163005         Austin      TX   30.31622   -97.85877
    3 10215 W. Jamesburg Street        Wichita      KS   37.70063   -97.43430
    4         14556 Newport Ave         Tustin      CA   33.74165  -117.82127
    5      2496 Falcon Crescent Virginia Beach      VA   36.83840   -76.02862
    6   1306 Wilshire Boulevard   Santa Monica      CA   34.03216  -118.49022
```

I would like to group together address and lat/long and put it all under the category of company.

I would like it to look like this:

```
     {company: {address: {address:  "5601 W. Slauson Ave. #200" ,
                          city.x:  "Culver City" ,
                          state.x:  "CA"}},
               {geo: {latitude: "33.99718",
                      longitude: "-118.40145"}}},

     {company: {address: {address:  "PO 163005" ,
                          city.x:  "Austin" ,
                          state.x:  "TX"}},
               {geo: {latitude: "30.31622",
                      longitude: "-97.85877"}}},



    structure(list(address = c("5601 W. Slauson Ave. #200", "PO 163005", 
    "10215 W. Jamesburg Street", "14556 Newport Ave", "2496 Falcon Crescent", 
    "1306 Wilshire Boulevard"), city.x = c("Culver City", "Austin", 
    "Wichita", "Tustin", "Virginia Beach", "Santa Monica"), state.x = c("CA", 
    "TX", "KS", "CA", "VA", "CA"), latitude.x = c(33.997179, 30.316223, 
    37.700632, 33.741651, 36.838398, 34.032159), longitude.x = c(-118.40145, 
    -97.85877, -97.4343, -117.82127, -76.02862, -118.49022)), .Names = c("address", 
    "city.x", "state.x", "latitude.x", "longitude.x"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    6L))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should output what you want:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  cat ("{company:{address:{adress:\t\"",df$address[i],
       "\",\n\t\tcity.x:\t\"", df$city.x[i],
       "\",\n\t\tstate.x:\t \"", df$state.x[i],
       "\"}}\n\t {geo:{\tlatitude: \"", df$latitude[i],
       "\",\n\t\tlongitude: \"", df$longitude[i],
       "\"}}},\n", sep="")
}
```

with `df` as your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `rjson` package.

```
require(rjson)
# This is necessary to avoid duplication of labels in the JSON output
names(df) <- NULL

reshaped <- apply(df, 1, FUN=function(x){list(address=list(
                                                  address = x[1],
                                                  city = x[2],
                                                  state = x[3]),
                                            coords=list(
                                                  latitude = x[4],
                                                  longitude = x[5]))})
result <- toJSON(reshaped)
```

The only difference from what you requested is that instead of having "company" as the root it will have sequential numbers. You could change it by changing the row names of your data (using `rownames`), but R does not support duplicate row names... the closest that I got was using

`rownames(df) <- paste("company", 1:nrow(df), collapse="")`

and maybe with a little regexp magic you could strip the numbers in the output string...